# How do you get the days for each month with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

I'm creating a calendar with JavaScript and need to be able to scroll to the next month and get the day the month starts on and be able to show all of the days in the month. I can do this for January but am confused how to make it work for each month when scrolling forward or backwards. Also I am able to scroll to the next month's name but am confused on how to get the days for the next month.

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 
'Septemeber', 'October', 'November', 'December']
var getMonths = document.querySelector('.twelvemonths');
var showMonth = document.querySelector('.show-month')
var showWeekDays = document.querySelector('.weekday');
var dateContainer = document.querySelector('.date-container');
var scrollRight = document.querySelector('.go-right');
var scrollLeft = document.querySelector('.go-left');
let weekDay = new Date();


let d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay();
let month = d.getMonth();
let year = d.getFullYear();

function getDaysInMonth(year, month){
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()
}

const getDays = getDaysInMonth(year, month)

function drawDays(){
    for(i = 1; i <= getDays; i ++){
        let calendarDay = document.createElement('div')
        calendarDay.className = 'calendar-day';
        calendarDay.innerHTML = i;
        dateContainer.appendChild(calendarDay);
    }
}

scrollRight.addEventListener('click', () =>{

   if(month < 11){
    month ++;
   } else {
    month = 0;
   }  

   showMonth.innerHTML = months[month];   
})

scrollLeft.addEventListener('click', () =>{
   month--;
   if(month < 0){
    month = 11;
   }
    showMonth.innerHTML = months[month]
})

showMonth.innerHTML = months[month];
drawDays()

switch(day){
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;
}
```

Comment: this looks like its missing html, please make [mcve]. Why is day selection a switch and not just a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this code ,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <style>
       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calendar">
        <button class="go-left">Previous</button>
        <div class="show-month"></div>
        <button class="go-right">Next</button>
        <div class="date-container"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 
            'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        var getMonths = document.querySelector('.twelvemonths');
        var showMonth = document.querySelector('.show-month');
        var dateContainer = document.querySelector('.date-container');
        var scrollRight = document.querySelector('.go-right');
        var scrollLeft = document.querySelector('.go-left');
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
        var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();

        function updateCalendar(year, month) {
             dateContainer.innerHTML = '';
            showMonth.innerHTML = months[month] + ' ' + year;
            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
            var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
            var daysOfWeek = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
            for (var i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
                var dayHeader = document.createElement('div');
                dayHeader.className = 'calendar-day-header';
                dayHeader.innerHTML = daysOfWeek[i];
                dateContainer.appendChild(dayHeader);
            }
            for (var day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
                var calendarDay = document.createElement('div');
                calendarDay.className = 'calendar-day';
                calendarDay.innerHTML = day;
                dateContainer.appendChild(calendarDay);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < firstDay; i++) {
                var emptyDay = document.createElement('div');
                emptyDay.className = 'calendar-day empty';
                dateContainer.insertBefore(emptyDay, dateContainer.firstChild);
            }
        }
        updateCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);

        scrollRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (currentMonth < 11) {
                currentMonth++;
            } else {
                currentMonth = 0;
                currentYear++;
            }
            updateCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);
        });

        scrollLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (currentMonth > 0) {
                currentMonth--;
            } else {
                currentMonth = 11;
                currentYear--;
            }
            updateCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```